# Reshaping Pandas column to show an image

Tags: python, pandas, image, reshape

I have a pandas dataframe where its column has a length of 256. How can I extract a column in order to create a 16*16 image and show it?
My problem is I don't know to choose a column a create a 16*16 object

I tried with pivot but this doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Select column, convert to numpy array and `reshape`:

```
arr = df['col'].values.reshape(16, 16)
```